# Input component don't have accept prop?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to restrict image format for the material UI Input component by adding accept props(as like default input tag). But when I add accept prop it throws an error. Am I using the correct component?. Is there any other way to restrict image Formats? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `inputProps={{ accept: "image/*" }}`? [Docs](https://material-ui.com/api/input/)

Comment: @Hangindev No I didn't, Thanks it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inputProps` prop to apply attributes to the `input` element. [Read more in Docs](https://material-ui.com/api/input/)